# Low Graphics Mode Error after clean 14.04.2 LTS installation

Tags: 14.04, graphics, windows-8, amd-graphics

A couple of days ago I decided to install Ubuntu on my computer that runs Windows 8.1. I downloaded LiLi USB Creator, ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso, and used it to create a 100Gb partition and install Ubuntu there.

Everything went fine, I was able to reboot, install Java JDK, and other stuff. When I went into Windows again and back to Ubuntu I got the dreaded Low Graphics Mode error, and I couldn't reach the login screen.

I tried entering fail safe mode and install drivers for my AMD GPU using `sudo apt-get install fglrx`.

I tried editing the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file because I read something about a bug, but this file was not present in the mentioned folder.

I tried switching from lightdm to gdm using [these instructions](http://simpledeveloper.com/system-running-in-low-graphics-mode/).
Nothing worked, so I reinstalled the same version of Ubuntu. The same thing happened again, without me changing/installing anything or entering Windows in between. I tried installing everything again.
I tried updating my programs using some GUI in the sidebar as well as using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

I tried installing the 14.04.2 LTS version instead.
When trying to install drivers using `fglrx` in this version, it complains about dependencies.

After some installations I'm able to reach the login GUI a couple of times, and after some I go directly to the graphics error. I have done so many re-installations and tried so many things in so many orders that my head is about to explode.

Is there something I should reconfigure in my BIOS? Does my 2x AMD 280x GPUs in crossfire have anything to do with it?

Can someone more experienced than me help me to troubleshoot this?

**EDIT:**
I've mainly used [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) when trying to troubleshoot. I've tried most of the things that I've found relevant. The post is also quite old, and some of the solutions are out-dated. I also have a problem that I haven't seen anywhere else: The error occurs randomly after a fresh installation. That is why I've created my own post about the problem.

Comment: Yes, this post tries to solve the same issue, and this is the main post I've investigated when trying to solve my own problem. I've also tried most of the things mentioned there that have seemed relevant in my case. But the post is 2 years old, and some of the solutions aren't relevant, such as the lightdm bug. My problem seems to occur somewhat randomly, something that I haven't read anywhere else. For these reasons I've created my own post about it.

Comment: this really *is* a duplicate imho - OP fixed it by installing AMD driver in the way explained in the top answer to the canonical post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I solved it (meaning I haven't had the Low Graphics Error now for about 10 reboots) by installing drivers for my GPU (2x 280X AMD cross-fire). I've done this previously with no success, but I guess I then had tried some other things before installing the drivers that messed it up. To help others with the same problem I'll explain what I did in detail.

1. After a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS and reboot I got the Low Graphics Mode error.
2. I rebooted into Windows 8.1, went to [AMD's website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) and downloaded the drivers for my GPU (Ubuntu 64bit in my case), and unzipped the folder to a 4 GB USB 2.0 stick.
3. I booted back into Ubuntu.
4. My USB didn't show up under `/media` so I had to manually mount it with the help if [this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB).

   1. I ran `sudo fdisk -l` to see that my USB was under `/dev/sdc` (the only unit that had ~4 GB space on it) and that it was formatted as FAT16.
   2. I ran `sudo mkdir /media/external` to create the folder for mounting the USB.
   3. I ran `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /media/external` to mount the USB in the folder.
5. I ran `sudo mkdir /home/john/amd_driver` to create a folder on by Ubuntu system in my user folder to place the driver (I didn't dare to install it from the USB stick itself).
6. I ran `sudo cp -r /media/external/fglrx-14.501.1003 /home/john/amd_driver` to copy the driver folder from my USB to my user directory.
7. I followed the installer instructions (http:// support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Catalyst-Linux-Installer-Notes.aspx) from AMD's website of how to install the driver (I had no previous driver so I skipped the first steps for uninstalling that)

   1. I ran `sudo sh ./amd-driver-installer-14.501.1003-x86.x86_64.run` while inside the `/home/john/amd_driver/fglrx-14.501.1003` folder, and followed the instructions.
   2. The "Generate Distribution..." option did not work, so I chose the "Install Driver..." option instead.
   3. I ran `/usr/bin/aticonfig --initial` to configure the newly installed driver.
8. After rebooting, everything has worked since then.